# M2E Pro and Magmi Setup

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, m2e, brightpearl

I have implemented a third-party Inventory Management Software (Bright Pearl). The software keeps tracks of quantity in Magento store to match the quantity with other stores which are also connected to BrightPearl.
Problem is: M2E does not pick up Quantity changes that are sent from BrightPearl to Magento.

Example: In BrightPearl “Product X” quantity changes from 10 to 7. It sends signal to Magento store, and in Magento the quantity for “Product X” changes to 7 (We are good!). The issue is that M2E does not pick-up a change of 7. It continues to show Product X quantity as 10. I have to manually go to “Product X” in Magento and save it. This way M2E will see the new quantity of 7.

I read that M2E can programmatically be notified to pick-up changes using Magmi.

Could someone shed some light into, how to set up Magmi ?

If you have other suggestions how to notify M2E of such changes, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

you would need to unstall magmi plugin under m2e pro. the problem with 3rd party 9inc. Bright Peral) is that these often do not follow Magento API and inject SQL rather than updating models ...